# Static compilation for wpa_supplicant

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation, static, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to compile a static binary of wpa_supplicant:

Latest - https://www.w1.fi/releases/wpa_supplicant-2.10.tar.gz

Other similar - https://github.com/blunderbuss-wctf/wacker/tree/master/wpa_supplicant-2.8

But I'm not able to achieve it.

I've read about launch `./configure --enable-static` before compilation, but this project has no `./configure` file.

After some googling, this is what I've tried:

-Add `-static` to the CFLAGS line (line 6) in Makefile

-Modifying LDDFLAGS line (line 118) to remove -rdynamic setting there -static

When I launch a `file` command over the resulting wpa_supplicant binary, it always says `dynamically linked` so it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem when trying to compile a statically linked binary for `wpa_supplicant`, i ended up finding [wifi_tools_static](https://github.com/drygdryg/wifi_tools_static), there you can find scripts and instructions on how to build and generate fully static binaries for both `wpa_supplicant` and even `iwd` if you need to

I've ran the scripts provided by the repo linked above on an Alpine Docker container, and tested the generated binaries on a very minimal Linux system that i'm working on, containing only the kernel and some busybox utils, and it worked flawlessly, `wpa_cli`, `wpa_passphrase` and `wpa_supplicant`

Comment: Thanks, but finally it was achieved using this: https://www.magicermine.com/trial.html

Comment: I tested that github repo you suggested before your post, and it worked compiling it with a very basic config file. If many options are added, more dependencies are needed and it started to crash a lot, but as I said in my last comment, it worked using that statifier

Comment: I'll try with ermine and see if it works for me, thanks for sharing

Comment: yeah, but bear in mind that ermine tool is not free. You can compile the binary for free only for 15 days to test

Comment: I've gave it a try and the results were pretty good, but by being a proprietary software it ends up being a dealbreaker for me